# FontForge - Why do Python scripts not work through "File->Execute Script"

Tags: python, windows-10, fontforge

this used to work on this very machine: I open a font in FontForge in Windows 10 (graphical user interface, not through command-line). Before (roughly a year ago) I was able to execute Python scripts from within the program by using the menu: "File -> Execute Script".

Now when I enter a script - "Python" radio button selected - nothing happens. Nothing. No result from the script, no error message, only the "Execute Script" window closes as if the script was executed. I tried simple, one-command scripts to test, like only calling Close() or "Select("xxxx")" without luck.

How can I trouble-shoot this? Am I missing some obvious prerequisite?

I'm running FontForge 8:20 and have 3.5.1 (64bit) installed on my Windows 10 machine. Thanks a lot for any thoughts.

[image]

Update: I reinstalled FontForge and updated Python. Still nothing happening when I try to run a script.